# Posted 10 messages, with 1 or more starred

Tags: support, chat

I talked with so many people in chat still I am not get any talkative Badges. If there is any bug or this?

Please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you *earn* a star for at least one message?

You have to meet **both** requirements:

- 10 or more messages;
- 1 or more starred.

Comment: Yes I achieve both requirement still I am not got.

Comment: @KeyulShah - you did not achieve both requirements. I see no starred chat messages of yours in any Magento chat room.

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12611/discussion-between-mohammad-faisal-and-keyul-shah

this is my chat room

Comment: ...and there is no starred message of yours. You would see those listed on the right.

Comment: can you please make photo of your starred message